# Why do themes rely on "The Loop"?

Tags: loop, themes

I've been looking at Wordpress themes development recently, and I'm trying to understand why Wordpress is coded with "The Loop", rather than providing an array of posts that you can loop through with a foreach.

It just seems to add complexity for theme development, but surely if they went out of there way to create this concept of "loop" there must be a reason?

Comment: Related reading, if you haven't already checked it out: [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [The Loop in action](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are thinking of WordPress templates as PHP application code. Essentially they are not that.

WordPress templates by design are templates using [Template Tags API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags). It is extra level of abstraction, that just happens to allow to use rest of PHP language too.

The ease of template tags serves the popularity of WordPress and extremely low entry bar for people to tweak themes. Believe me, there are plenty of people around who use/tweak loops without much understanding of what they actually are, in extreme cases, what **arrays** even are.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is just an abstraction of the process of iterating over the posts returned by a query. As with all abstractions you pay some performance price for not using directly the language constructs like arrays, but it creates a more readable code (hopefully) as `$q->hove_posts()` is easier to grasp then `($I++ < count($q->$posts))`.

The main reason of why themes follow the loop although they are not really required (there are some hooks that can be called while iterating loop style, but I don't think they are used much) is probably that all tutorials and the themes that are included with wordpress use it, ie simple inertia, but I never have seen anyone claiming that the loop is bad in any real way therefor there isn't much point in trying to do it in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Every query object contains an array of the returned posts, so technically you could use foreach to display the posts, but I don't think it would simplify anything. First of all, you'll lose the loop start and end actions, and the ability to know if code is being executed within the loop or not, but the major thing you'll lose is the current post context - all template tags would have to pass the context of which post you're currently working with.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress data is all centered around the concept of "The Post" which is really little more that a colloquialism used to describe a complex array of data stored in the database. The pieces of data in that array make sense together in context.

So technically, sure, you could extract all that data from that array with a foreach if you really wanted to. But why bother? "The Loop" (also, kind of a colloquialism) really simplifies theme development, rather than creating complexity. It provides you with the ability to use all the convenience methods to extract whichever type of data (from the current "post" in your iteration) you desire to display in your theme.

What's simpler than this?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    // get that data, bro. Put it in the  middle of some HTML, if you want.
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    // or don't, who cares?
<?php endif; ?>
```

If this makes more sense to you, go for it:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        // Oh sweet, I can echo everything and concatenate stuff!
    } // end while
} // end if
```

Reference: [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)